# Difference between mkdir() and mkdirs() in java for java.io.File

Tags: java, android, directory, android-file

Can anyone tell me the difference between these two methods:

- `file.mkdir()`
- `file.mkdirs()`

Comment: Read the javadoc: [mkdir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) vs [mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Comment: The newer way to do it is using Files.createDirectories and Files.createDirectory static methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: You can get "File not supported" after using mkdir.

Comment: **Is there any performance differences between the two? _Especially when the parent directories already exist?_**

Answer (score 177):

`mkdirs()` also creates **parent directories** in the path this `File` represents.

[javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) for `mkdirs()`:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.

[javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) for `mkdir()`:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.

**Example:**

```
File  f = new File("non_existing_dir/someDir");
System.out.println(f.mkdir());
System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
```

will yield `false` for the first [and no dir will be created], and `true` for the second, and you will have created `non_existing_dir/someDir`

Comment: Because oracle is breaking links in the internet again: [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) and [mkdir()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29)

Comment: If the directory already exists, does `mkdir()` return `true` or `false`? The javadoc does not seem to cover this aspect.

Comment: @Arun, according to the Javadoc it returns "true if and only if the directory was created", which I suppose is ambiguous as to whether it was created by this call or earlier.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12204054/894885) suggests the former.

Comment: mkdir and mkdirs return both false in my case -.-. It works if i use double backslash "\\" BUT: 
if i do ".toURI()" after that i receive: file:/Users/MyName/Desktop/%5Cnon_existing_dir%5CsomeDir/ 
and if i do ".getPath()" i receive "\non_existing_dir\someDir" 
and if i do ".getCanonicalPath()" i receive /Users/MyName/Desktop/\non_existing_dir\someDir

Comment: @amit mkdirs works flawlessly!

Comment: it is similar to -p argument for mkdir in linux

Answer (score 67):

`mkdirs()` will create the specified directory path in its entirety where `mkdir()` will only create the bottom most directory, failing if it can't find the parent directory of the directory it is trying to create.

In other words `mkdir()` is like `mkdir` and `mkdirs()` is like `mkdir -p`.

For example, imagine we have an empty `/tmp` directory.  The following code

```
new File("/tmp/one/two/three").mkdirs();
```

would create the following directories:

- `/tmp/one`
- `/tmp/one/two`
- `/tmp/one/two/three`

Where this code:

```
new File("/tmp/one/two/three").mkdir();
```

would not create any directories - as it wouldn't find `/tmp/one/two` - and would return `false`.

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir()
```

creates only one directory at a time, if it is parent that one only. other wise it can create the sub directory(if the specified path is existed only) and do not create any directories in between any two directories. so it can not create smultiple directories in one directory

```
mkdirs()
```

create the multiple directories(in between two directories also) at a time.