# File.mkdir or mkdirs return false - Reason?

Tags: java, file, javadoc, mkdir

Why file.mkdir is returning false?

Google indicates that there could be several reasons (e.g. security, permissions, pathname, etc).

My questions:

1. How to find the exact reason of returning false?
2. If security/permissions is a reason, then why is SecurityException not thrown?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> If security/permissions is a reason, then why is SecurityException NOT thrown (which is mentioned in javadoc)?

A `SecurityException` is thrown when you don't have JVM-level permission to do something, not OS-level

> Is there a way to find the exact reason why of returning false?

No, AFAIK. The only way to know would be to check the permissions on the directory yourself, make sure it doesn't exist before calling them, check if the parent directory exists, etc.

However, if you're using **Java 7 or higher**, you can use NIO instead to create the directory. Specifically, [`Files.createDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)):

```
File dir = new File("mydir");
Files.createDirectory(dir.toPath());
```

If you want to use NIO entirely without using `java.io.File`, you can use [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) to create a `Path` instead:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("mydir");
Files.createDirectory(dir);
```

In both cases, if the directory can't be created, it will throw an `IOException` with an exact reason for why the operation failed.

This is true for most of the methods in `Files`, and so using it is recommended over using the methods in the `File` class.

Comment: With "mkdir", if you are trying to mkdir("/path1/path2/"); and the path1 (parent) folder not existed before you execute the command, the mkdir will fail, it can only create a new folder inside an existed folder, mkdirs can create all folders - path1 and path2. I have no clue with the failing of mkdirs. Hope it help

Comment: @Andiana Correct. That's because Java's `File.mkdir` follows Linux conventions instead of Windows conventions, and it doesn't create intermediate directories. `File.mkdirs` follows Windows conventions, and it behaves like `mkdir --parents` in Linux. Good point. Still, for getting the exact reason, Michael's answer below is the best one: use Java's NIO packages.

Answer (score 47):

mkdir and mkdirs return false if the directory already exists, so that might be one reason for the failure.

If you are using Java 7, you can use the Files class.  It throws an IOException on error with pretty good descriptions.

```
Files.createDirectory(file.toPath());
```

Comment: It returns false if the directory already exists or if there was an error creating the directory. Now there's a piece of useful API.

Comment: In `Android` API 26 or above required! Any backward compatibility?

Answer (score 7):

1. No, there's no way to find the exact reason `mkdirs()` returns false, at least not from within Java, as it would probably be OS dependent.
2. A `SecurityException` is thrown if there is a security violation in the `SecurityManager`'s `checkRead()` and `checkWrite()` methods. The exception isn't thrown if there is an OS permissions issue.

---

Additionally, note that if you call `File.mkdir()`, and the parent directory doesn't exist, `mkdir()` will return false. However, calling `File.mkdirs()` will create the non-existent parent directories.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something specific to Windows: In my case, the `file.mkdir()` method was failing with `NoSuchFileException` because I was trying to create a nested directory structure directly (e.g. `results\results_ddMMyyyy` without first creating the `results` directory) on Windows.

However, the exact same code worked fine on my Mac, i.e. no such exception was thrown on Mac and the intermediate `results` directory was created implicitly by the `file.mkdir()` method.

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: This is actually similar to my case, I have a legacy tool written in java and executed as a jar file in a Linux VM, when I tried to run it on Windows, one of the errors related to the code being too OS specific is the nested directory situation.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't include "/" before the path I gave which made my path wrong and hence failure.

> What I was doing

```
"Talkify/Media/Picture/Sent"
```

> What it should look like

```
"/Talkify/Media/Picture/Sent"
```