# folder not creating in linux through java program

Tags: java, linux, file

I am trying to create folder and write images in it from war using following code:

```
// war directory : /opt/apache-tomcat/webapps/mj.war

String absoluteDiskPath = "tmp/mjpics/images/travel_schedule";
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
if (!file.exists()) {
    if (file.mkdir()) {
        System.out.println("Directory is created!");
        try {
            writeText(textcontent, textFileName, eventDate, eventCat, absoluteDiskPath+"\\"+eventCat+"\\"+eventName);
            writeImage(imagecontent, imageFileName, eventDate, eventCat, absoluteDiskPath+"\\"+eventCat+"\\"+eventName);
            imagecontent.close();
            textcontent.close();
            UplodedData.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ouput: Failed to create directory.

Comment: Add an exception block to check for the error message why is couldn't create the dir. Mostly a permissions issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File.mkdir or mkdirs return false - Reason?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202766/file-mkdir-or-mkdirs-return-false-reason)

Comment: Use `mkdirs()` instead, if parent dirs do not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `absoluteDiskPath` isn't absolute. Not sure if that's intentional, but you are missing a slash in front of it.
Also, I am guessing, you want `.mkdirs` instead of `.mkdir`. The plural form creates all the folders in the path, the singular will only create the last one, and fail if the rest of the path does not exist.

I.e., if you are trying to create a folder "foo/bar/baz", `.mkdir` will fail unless you already have a folder " foo" in your current directory, containing a folder named "bar" inside of it.

Comment: parent dirs are existing, i want to create travel_schedule only

Comment: Then I guess, it's the missing slash problem. You are trying to create this patn in your current directory, which is almost always wrong.

Comment: their are two different directories
/tmp/mjpics and war is in another directories

Comment: This has nothing to do with where war is.

Comment: Worked for me 
String absoluteDiskPath = "/tmp/mjpics/images/travel_schedule"