# Java: Why doesn't this create the last folder?

Tags: java, file, mkdir

```
public static void VDirectoryMaker(File des) {
        if (!des.exists()) {
            File dest = new File(des.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, des.getAbsolutePath().length()-(des.getName().length())));
            VDirectoryMaker(dest);
            dest.mkdir();
        }
    }
```

If `des` equals `new File("dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4\\dir5")` why does it only make all non-existing folders up to dir4? dir5 is never created.

Comment: Use [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) instead [mkdir()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29).

Comment: Have a look at [Difference between mkdir() and mkdirs() in java for java.io.File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820088/difference-between-mkdir-and-mkdirs-in-java-for-java-io-file). It'll give u answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the last `dir5` is treated as file without extension inside the `dir4` directory.

Try adding last backslash, the directories should be created as you expected.

```
new File("dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4\\dir5\\")
```

You should also look at [`File.mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()).

Answer (score 0):

This code is removing the last part of the path:

```
des.getAbsolutePath().substring(
  0, des.getAbsolutePath().length()-(des.getName().length()))
```

This would work if your input was a complete file path for a file, eg:

```
VDirectoryMaker(new File("dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4\\targetfile.txt");
```