# Mkdir Creates Parent Directory If not exist

Tags: java

When I use below code, Its creating \scrshot\vb\uv even though \scrshot\vb not exist in D drive.

```
takeScreenshot("D:\\scrshot\\vb\\uv", "s.png");

    public void takeScreenshot(String fileDir,String fileName)
    {


        File directory=new File(fileDir);
        if(!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdir();
        File file=((TakesScreenshot)ddr).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(file,new File(directory.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

If my understanding is correct mkdir() would not create parent folder if it does not exist. but here its creating \scrshot\vb\ under D drive. this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820088/difference-between-mkdir-and-mkdirs-in-java-for-java-io-file) for reference.

Comment: Are you sure that the directory isn't being created by `FileUtils.copyFile()`?

Comment: please mention JDK version.

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: @Kenster You are right. FileUtils.copyFile() creates the folder structure not mkdir(). Can you please explain why its happening in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Apache Commons `FileUtil`. The [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) states clearly that the directory containing the destination File will be created if it doesn't exist:

> This method copies the contents of the specified source file to the
>   specified destination file. **The directory holding the destination file
>   is created if it does not exist.** If the destination file exists, then
>   this method will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

mkdir() never create parent directory

but in your code

```
FileUtils.copyFile(file,new File(directory.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+fileName));
```

This line is responsible to create a directory.