# Problem with copying files to another non-existing directory Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, file, directory

I have a problem with copying files to another directory within a Kotlin method. It seems that I can't copy the text files from one directory to other.

I want to copy the files into a directory that has not been created yet.

```kotlin
import java.io.File

fun createCommitDirectory(
    parentFile: File,
    directoryIdHashName: String,
    indexFile: File,
    rootFile: File
) {
    val directory = File("${parentFile}/${directoryIdHashName}")
    if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdir()

    val firstFile = rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()
        .first { it.name == "${indexFile.readLines().elementAt(0)}" }

    val secondFile = rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()
        .first { it.name == "${indexFile.readLines().elementAt(2)}" }

    firstFile.copyTo(File("${parentFile}/${directoryIdHashName}"))
    secondFile.copyTo(File("${parentFile}/${directoryIdHashName}"))
}
```

I tried using the copy `Recursive()` method as well, but it doesn't seem to work either. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello Max, can you share the error message with us, please?

Answer (score 1):

A potential point of failure would be the usage of `mkdir` instead of `mkdirs`, also some null-safety issues spotted for first and second file property accessors.

Therefore, I would refactor the following to:

```kotlin
import java.io.File

fun createCommitDirectory(
    parentFile: File,
    directoryIdHashName: String,
    indexFile: File,
    rootFile: File
) {
    val directory = File("${parentFile}/${directoryIdHashName}")
        .apply(File::mkdirs)

    rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()
        ?.first { it.name == indexFile.readLines().elementAt(0) }
        ?.copyTo(directory)

    rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()
        ?.first { it.name == indexFile.readLines().elementAt(2) }
        ?.copyTo(directory)
}
```

[javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) for `mkdirs()`:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

For the difference between `mkdir()` and `mkdirs()`, see: [stackoverflow.com/a/9820115/5037430](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820115/5037430)

Then, we could take this one more step, and add some error handling to the nullables:

```kotlin
import java.io.File

fun createCommitDirectory(
    parentFile: File,
    directoryIdHashName: String,
    indexFile: File,
    rootFile: File
) {
    val directory = File("${parentFile}/${directoryIdHashName}")
        .apply(File::mkdirs)

    rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()
        ?.first { it.name == indexFile.readLines().elementAt(0) }
        ?.copyTo(directory)
        ?: error("Could not find file at index: 0")

    rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()
        ?.first { it.name == indexFile.readLines().elementAt(2) }
        ?.copyTo(directory)
        ?: error("Could not find file at index: 2")
}
```

[Error](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/error.html) is a Kotlin built-in:

> Error throws an IllegalStateException with the given message.

However, the error reporting above might not be good enough to figure out what is the problem, so we can introduce better error reporting by including the directory and indexed element when an exception is thrown:

```kotlin
import java.io.File

fun createCommitDirectory(
    parentFile: File,
    directoryIdHashName: String,
    indexFile: File,
    rootFile: File
) {
    File("${parentFile}/${directoryIdHashName}")
        .apply(File::mkdirs)
        .let { directory ->
            rootFile.canonicalFile.parentFile.listFiles()?.let { children ->
                val indexFileLines = indexFile.readLines()
                val indexedElement0 = indexFileLines.elementAt(0)
                val indexedElement2 = indexFileLines.elementAt(2)

                children
                    .first { it.name == indexedElement0 }
                    ?.copyTo(directory)
                    ?: errorReporter(indexedElement0, children)

                children
                    .first { it.name == indexedElement2 }
                    ?.copyTo(directory)
                    ?: errorReporter(indexedElement2, children)
        }
    }
}

fun errorReporter(indexedElement0: String, children: Array<out File>) {
    error("Indexed file name: $indexedElement0 did not match any file in the directory: ${children.toList()}")
}
```

Do note, without the actual error message, it would be hard to understand what is going on. However, try running the above and see if you can spot the error now.

Goodluck.